# Android Textview Spannable disregards newlines and trailing whitespace

Tags: android, html, markdown, textview

I'm trying to display a piece of code in a `TextView`. The code lines are spanned in `<pre><code>` tags. Before calling `Html.fromHtml()` on the `String`, I can clearly see the tabbing and newlines, but when I call the `fromHtml()` to convert it to a `Spannable`, it loses all whitespacing in the `<pre><code>` tags.

Here is how it looks before `fromHtml`:

[image: before]

And here is how it looks after `fromHtml`:

[image: after]

This of course is very hard to read. How should I try fixing it? Keep in mind that it only happens on newlines and whitespaces in the `<code>` tags. The `<p>` tags handle newlines fine.

Comment: You may want to give the [`HtmlSpanner` library](https://github.com/NightWhistler/HtmlSpanner) a try. I've never used it myself, but according to the documentation it should support `<pre>`, although not `<code>`. It seems easily extensible enough though. As it appears to rely on `HtmlCleaner`, it's probably not a good idea to do any of the processing on the UI thread.

Comment: @MH. will definitely give a look at that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless Google added it when I wasn't looking, [`<pre>` and `<code>` are both not supported by `fromHtml()` at all](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) -- they, like all other unrecognized tags, are simply stripped out.

You can try to use a `TagHandler` here, but I am unconvinced that it will help much with the newlines.

What you might be able to do is convert the `<pre>` tags into `<p>` tags (if you like `<p>` newline handling), then use `TagHandler` to convert `<code>` into a monospace `TypefaceSpan`.

On my 18,000-item to-do list is to write a better `fromHtml()` replacement...

Comment: I'm actually using your AndDown library. Unlike stated in the AndDown repo, Bypass is not the superior solution as it has a lot of issues for me. I also use my own TagHandler to set a Background and Typeface on the `<code>` tags. But I hadn't thought about converting the `<pre>` tags.

Comment: It seems the `<code>` tag actually overrides any `<p>` spanning, as it gets handled by a different `TagHandler` (my own one). How difficult would it be to write my own `fromHtml()`?

Comment: @tolgap: I haven't really tried to scope out the level of effort. My one concrete warning is to avoid TagSoup, as Android uses that internally, and so you'll run into possible compatibility issues (OS copy of the JAR will be used in place of yours). Either refactor TagSoup into another package, or find another HTML parser. However, if your *whole* HTML is wrapped in `<code>`, just get rid of those tags and put in the typeface in around the whole result. I can't tell if the HTML you show in your question is the complete HTML or a subset.

Comment: It's a subset with other <p> tags and other tags. I will give a shot at creating my own `fromHtml()` without stripping whitespaces. I found the documentation for it. Thanks.